# what do you call the black bar at the bottom of the Honeycomb interface?

Tags: 3.0-honeycomb

I'm googling for a problem with the black bar on the bottom of my ASUS Transformers screen. the one with the navagation icons, notifications, and battery info. I'm not sure what the official name for that UI element is.

ps: i solved my origional problem. this bar thickens to addjust the aspect ratio when using HDMI output though I still dont know it's name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question on what the 'black bar' is at the bottom of the screen - it appears to be called the `System Bar`.  I thought it was the `Notification Bar` but apparently that is part of the `System Bar`.

Here are several links that I found in my search:

[Android 3.0 Highlights from Android Developer site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.0-highlights.html)

[TalkAndroid.com](http://www.talkandroid.com/28330-android-3-0-honeycomb-sdk-released-features-images-and-changes/honeycomb-system-bar/)

[Esato.com](http://www.esato.com/board/viewtopic.php?topic=200429)

[PhoneArena.com](http://www.phonearena.com/image.php?m=Articles.Images&f=name&id=38451&name=Motorola_XOOM_Review_Screens_006.jpg&caption=The%20System%20Bar%20is%20in%20the%20bottom%20of%20the%20screen&title=Image%20from%20%22Android%203.0%20Honeycomb%20Walkthrough%22&kw=android)

[StackOverflow Question where someone called it a 'System Bar'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109988/is-there-a-way-to-hide-the-system-bar-in-android-3-0-its-an-internal-device-and)